# How to get single item in pyrebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hopefully a pretty easy questions follows. When I get an item with Pyrebase's .get() method, like so:

```
for company_id in game[company_type]:
    pyre_company = db.child("companies/data").order_by_child("id").equal_to(company_id).limit_to_first(
        1).get()
    company = pyre_company.val()
    print(company)
    break # Run only once for testing purposes
```

I get this following output, even though I use the ***.val()***

```
OrderedDict([('-LEw2zHYiJ6p15iBhKuZ', {'id': 427, 'name': 'Bugbear Entertainment', 'type': 'developer'})])
```

But I only want the JSON Object

```
{'id': 427, 'name': 'Bugbear Entertainment', 'type': 'developer'}
```

Comment: It might be because of the `.order_by_child("id").equal_to(company_id).limit_to_first(1)`. Just a guess.

Comment: I actually know it's because of this, but was wondering how to fix it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because

```
db.child("companies/data").order_by_child("id").equal_to(company_id).limit_to_first(1).get()
```

is a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), because you call the `orderByChild()` method on a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) (as well as an `equalTo()` method btw).

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) in the JavaScript SDK doc:

> Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a 
>   list; it just contains a single item. To access the item,
>   you need to loop over the result:
>
> ```
> ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {  
>   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>     var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
>     var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>     // ...   
>    }); 
> });
> ```

With pyrebase you should use the `each()` method, as explained [here](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#each), which "Returns a list of objects on each of which you can call `val()` and `key()`".

```
pyre_company = db.child("companies/data").order_by_child("id").equal_to(company_id).limit_to_first(1).get()
for company in pyre_company.each(): 
    print(company.val()) // {'id': 427, 'name': 'Bugbear Entertainment', 'type': 'developer'}
```

Comment: Than you very much. You're the boss!

Comment: I am getting following error                           raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://firebaseid.firebaseio.com/myprojectname.json?orderBy=%2522%2524key%2522] {
  "error" : "orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"
}

Comment: Can you please give any suggestion

Comment: @NarenderReddy Hello. Without more details on your database format and what you are exactly doing it is difficult to give a suggestion. I would suggest you write a new question with as much detail as possible. Your current code, the error, the log, at which line is the error occurring, etc.

Comment: I would like to have the like clause similar to this SQL example: select * from house where child like '%elias%'